# is there a way to get the error "dksd : command not found" in the stderr, without having to fork the process?

Tags: c, shell

Basically I'm trying to create a shell using C, and one of the issues I did encounter is with the random inputs. So in a normal Linux shell, if I type something random I get the error `"sdjk: command not found"` for example. Now I want to make that work in my shell too, but I want to detect if a command exists or not and also output the error message without having to `fork` the process.

The issue is that I use `execve` function to execute my commands. Whenever `execve` is used, it just terminates the process once it's done, so is there a way to circumvent that?

Also this is my first post, so I don't know if I'm asking for help the right way.

```
int _system(char *command) {
    char *argv[] = {"shell", "-c", command, NULL};
    execve("/bin/sh", argv, NULL);
    perror("execve");
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    printf("hello there world\n");
    
    if (_system("vsvdvq") == -1) {
        perror("Error executing ls");
    }

    printf("hello there world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Now this is a little simulation because I can't put the whole actual shell code here. I get the error message that I want when the input is wrong, but I want the program to keep functioning even after the output of the error message. That doesn't seem possible without using `fork`, and I don't want to use `fork`.

Comment: You could do the `$PATH` search yourself.  But it's easier just to do the `fork()`.  Why do you wish to avoid forking?

Comment: Citing [`man execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html): "On success, `execve()` does not return, on error -1 is returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error." If the program does not exist or cannot be executed you can check `errno` and print an appropriate error message from the child process. Of course this requires to execute your command (`vsvdvq`) directly instead of ececuting `/bin/sh` and passing the command as an argument. Currently your code does not *implement* a (simple) shell but runs an existing shell.

Comment: because the shell project i'm working on is basically a task and they ask for fork to not be used in case the command doesn't exist, and i kind of struggled with that, i now just used the write() function to put the code error in the stderr directly and im hoping for the best

Comment: Note that `_system` is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  And if someone tells you, "But it works"?  No, it doesn't "work" - they just haven't observed it to fail - **yet**.  And `_system` **will** collide with an acutal `_system` symbol on almost all POSIX-based systems...